# wpf delete button click act like delete keydown in datagrid

Tags: button, datagrid, wpf-controls

hi i have a delete button, when i click that button i wish it can act like I pressed 'delete' key on a datagrid , it will remove the row from datagrid (won't write back to DB).

how can invoke that action in wpf?

thanks